# Grails remove first character of string

Tags: string, grails, groovy

I got a string like this:

```
params.search = abc def 123
```

in the string, name: abc and position: def 123

```
params.search.split(" ").each{ key->
    ilike ('name', key[0].toString())
    ilike ('position', ....
}
```

My problem is that how can I remove the name in string (first index of string), then set the rest of string for position in ilike()

Comment: @what is your desired output put it on the question please add info...question is not so clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for `name` to be `abc` and `position` to be `def 123`?

```
def string = "abc def 123"
def splitStr = string.split()

def name = splitStr[0]
def position = splitStr[1..-1].join(/ /)

assert name == 'abc'
assert position == 'def 123'
```

**UPDATE**
I would rather use [@Tim's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107767/2051952) because above approach is verbose.
Using [`split(regex, limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and multiple assignment makes the implementation groovier and smarter.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23107767/2051952) is the best possible answer to the question and should be accepted instead. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use multiple assignment and limit the results from `split`:

```
def str = "abc def 123"
def (name,position) = str.split( ' ', 2 )

assert name == 'abc'
assert position == 'def 123'
```

Comment: wow. This should be the accepted answer. I remember using this format, but forgot in the middle of the night while posting. Thanks, mate. +1